# Add whenTool tip on jQuery-Seat-Charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p5La.png)
I Would like to activate a tool tip when focused
[This is the exmple link](https://github.com/mateuszmarkowski/jQuery-Seat-Charts)

i am trying to add tool tip when a seat is hovered i am using mateusmarkowski jquery-seat chart but i find it hard to do it

Comment: looking at the offical demo fot jquery-seat chart, there is no tooltip feature whatsoever: https://jsc.mm-lamp.com/ Tooltip in your screenshot looks a lot like Bootstrap's.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.